# Android download file through browser

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

```
var uri = Droid.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

StartActivity(intent);
```

(Code is xamarin)

This code will open a page that is actually download of a PDF. After the file is downloaded, chrome will close the tab and show the last tab the user was looking at and pressing back will just continue to move back in chrome, not going back to the app.

Can it be done that when the file is downloaded user is returned to the app instead of being in chrome (or other browser)?

Comment: not used to xamarin. But instead of opening a browser with url, consider openning a http connection from your app. and saving the result file yourself. This way you would never leave your app.

Comment: Consider using startActivityForResult.

Comment: @Doomsknight I'm trying to avoid that.

RomanSamoylenko that didn't work, I'm still stuck in chrome

Comment: Once you have opened another app, you cannot interfere, aka have no control over its button interactions. In browsers, the backbutton is usually overriden to take you back to a previous url. Rather than back to the last activity. So it will not navigate back into your app. ForResult wont work, as it just listens for a result on return, but chrome never returns back to your app. Unless there is some specific intent info you can pass when opening it, to tell it, it should return on pressing back then it is not possible. (which i am unaware of)

Comment: @Doomsknight Ok, I thought if I start it with ClearTop it will be just that activity and back will be my app. It can be done, because Facebook app does it, just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ActivityFlags.NewTask you will get the desired effect. Only issue with downloading file is that the tab that downloads a file will close and you will get the tab that was opened before it, but if you press back button it will go back to your app.